# Exercise dealing with pigeonhole principle (even product)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Define $\mathbb{N}_n=\{1,...,n\}$

The pigeon hole principle as I know is that if $n>m$. Then for every map

$f:\mathbb{N}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_m$ there exists two distinct $n_1,n_2$ such that $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$

The excercise is if $a_1,...,a_n$ is an arrangement of the numbers $1,...,n$ then

$(a_1-1)(a_2-2)….(a_n-n)$ is even.

If the prduct would not be even then every factor would have to be uneven. That means $a_1,a_3,..a_n\in\{2,4,...,n-1\}$.

The only map that I have is the arrangement $f:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}$

How can I construct a contradiction with the pigeon hole principle as stated above now?

EDIT:

$n$ is uneven

Comment: If $n=2$ and $a_1=2,a_2=1$ then $(a_1-1)\times (a_2-2)=1\times (-1)=-1$ which is odd.

Comment: I forgot to Mention that n is uneven

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the important information.

Comment: Note:  if $n$ is odd then there are more odds than evens on the list, so not every odd can be mapped to an even.

Comment: $(2 - 1)(1 - 2) = -1$ which is not even. So the claim is not true in general. It is true for odd $n$ by lulu's argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

In order for this product to be odd, we need every factor in it to be odd.  Thus each number $i$ must be associated with another element of the set of the opposite parity.  Evens must be associated with odds, and odds with evens.  In particular, we need there to be as many evens as odds.

But:  if $n$ is odd then the list $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ contains more odds than evens.  Thus it is not possible that each odd $i$ is associated with a different even.

Note that, if $n$ is even, the claim is false.  We can just shift each element one unit to the right (cyclicly) to get an odd product.

Comment: +1: but we should goad the OP into fixing the question (as it is false for even $n$).

Comment: @RobArthan  I believe the OP fixed that (after prodding).   The edit specifies that "$n$ is uneven".

Comment: Yes, I see that has been fixed now in an erratum. There should be some advice somewhere about how to fix an MSE question (tagging on errata at the end is dumb). Cheers!

Comment: That also means that the set $\{a_1,a_3,...,a_n\}$ would have to contain at least one more element than the set $\{2,4,...,n-1\}$ which is also a contradiction that the element of the set $\{a_1,a_3,...,a_n\}$ are distinct(see my guesswork in the post)

Comment: @RM777  Not sure I follow.  where are you using the assumption that $n$ is odd.

Comment: $\{a1,a_3...,a_n\}$ is bijective to $\{1,3...,n\}$ i.e all odds which are more than all the evens $\{2,4,...,n-1\}$ (if $n-1=0$ then the set is empty). Here I am using the assumotion that n is odd. Then if the product is uneven I have deduced that all the numbers $a_1,a_3,...a_n$ have to be even. I.e there exists a map $f:\{a1,a_3...,a_n\}\rightarrow \{2,4,...,n-1\}$ (all $a_k$ are bounded by $n$ and we have said that the left set of the map must be all uneven) then by the pigeon hole principle and the assumption it follows there exists two same Elements in the set on the left.

Comment: This is then a contradiction that $a_1,...,a_n$ is a rearrangement

Comment: Well, it's hard to read.  I am guessing that by $\{a_1,a_3,\cdots, a_n\}$ you mean the terms with odd indices?  You don't ever say that, but I guess it makes sense.  Similar comment about $\{1,3,\cdots, n\}$.  Don't assume that your readers can guess what you have in mind!